# Архиважное, архаичное, археология, архитектура, архангел...

Tags: этимология, семантика, однокоренные-слова

Архиважное, архаичное, археология, архитектура, архангел – в этих словах прослеживается общий корень «арх», от которого веет санскритом. Являются ли они однокоренными и какова  суть этого корня?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приставка "архи-" обычно применяется в значении "главный", "высший". Корень "арх" в словах "археология", "архив" и т.п. - в значении "древний", "старый". В обоих случаях источник заимствования - греческий. Значения - похожи. Возможно, в языке заимствования есть прямая связь. В русском - нет.

Comment: Вот  почитайте: http://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/proizvodnye-ot-grecheskogo-kornya-arhv-russkom-yazyke-okonchanie